# Store location data when app is not running using Xcode 15.1 and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, core-location

I'm close but can't seem to get my app to store location data when not running. I'm trying to collect driver data. When I start the App it asks for location permission while using the App. At no time does the app ask me to give permission for allowing the app to collect information when I am not using the app. I think the problem revolves around this. I've also tried going into iOS settings for the app and set to Always but that didn't help. I'm likely missing something here in my code or in a setting to get it to collect the data when the app is not running. Any help is appreciated.
Here is what I've got.

For Signing I have Background Modes enabled with "Location updates". For plist.info I have the following set with descriptions.

- Privacy - Location Location Always Usage Description
- Privacy - Location When in Use Usage Description
- Privacy - LocationAways and When in Use Usage Description

I also have in the Info file: Required background modes with Item 0 set with "App registers for location updates"

for code I have the the following in the AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    static let shared = AppDelegate()
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Add any custom setup code here
        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate {
    func requestLocationAuthorization() {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}
```

For my app here is how I trigger the app delegate and start up the location manager

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct ZenTracApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    ...
```

for code I have the following LocationManager:

```
import CoreLocation
import SwiftData

@MainActor
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    //@Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    /// Override exiting init
    override init() {
        /// Bring in the normal init
        super.init()
        
        AppDelegate.shared.requestLocationAuthorization()
        
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    /// iOS triggers whenever the location changes
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let newLocation = locations.last else {return}
        
        /// Check if the location has changed significantly before updating in this case more than 10 meters
        if self.location == nil || location!.distance(from: newLocation) > 10 {
            self.location = newLocation
            // save the location info in this function
            saveEntry(location: self.location!)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to request when in use first and after the user says yes to that you request always

Comment: Ok. Had to ask for When and always then always in order.  That brings up the always when I restart the app.  Two problems still remain:  1. I would like to set the status to always before the user leaves the app so I don't loose collecting data until they launch again and th app asks.  I presume there is some way to set that programmatically or query the user for the permission.  Not sure how to do that.   2. Either way, app still not collecting and storing data when not running.

Comment: You can do it with the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3563956-locationmanagerdidchangeauthoriz) that triggers when authorization is changed and if by not running you mean "killed" that is expected. Apple doesn't allow apps to do most things when killed.

Comment: Adding "func locationManager(
        _ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus
    ) { ... }" let me ask for the Always Permission right after having both requests in the right order in the AppDelegate "requestLocationAuthorization() function"

Comment: So, I have the permission requests down and asked in the right order.  Now on to the challenge of collecting location data when the app is not actively running remains to be solved.  There is a way to do this.  There are a number of apps that collect location data when not "active" or in the "background".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/handling_location_updates_in_the_background

Comment: I have that covered.  It's looking more like I'll have to go down this route:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app